# Matching up until another expression in a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following series of strings. I need to only match up until a certain point in each one, leaving out the numbers after the file extension.

```
folder/file.ext
folder/folder/file.ext
file.ext
file.file.ext
folder/file.ext/320
folder/folder/file.ext/320
file.ext/320
file.file.ext/320
folder/file.ext/320/240
folder/folder/file.ext/320/240
file.ext/320/240
file.file.ext/320/240
```

In other words, I want to transform the above into:

```
folder/file.ext
folder/folder/file.ext
file.ext
file.file.ext
folder/file.ext
folder/folder/file.ext
file.ext
file.file.ext
folder/file.ext
folder/folder/file.ext
file.ext
file.file.ext
```

I was using the following expression to match the folder(s), file and extension:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_/.-]+
```

But it accidentally matches the `/000` or `/000/000` that can be tacked on after the filename.

This expression gets closer, but leaves out the `.ext`:

```
(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)
```

How do I write an expression that selected the folders, file and extension, but leaves out anything after the extension?

Comment: Is this OK for you: `^(.+\.[^/]+)`

Comment: @Toto That works absolutely perfectly, if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do simply:

```
^(.+\.[^/]+)
```

This will match the path + filename + extension and keep them in group 1.

It works only if there are no dots in the path after extension.